# How to set default value to empty EditorFor-field when post a form i .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form in .NET MVC 5. where the user can write a number, default is "0", If the user deletes a number e.g. "233" an leaving the field empty. The form would not submit.

How can I submit the form with an empty field?

```
public class myModel 
{
    public int nummer { get; set; }
    public myModel(){}
    public myModel(int i) {this.nummer = i;}
}
```

razor code:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("myAction", "myController", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text- danger" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nummer, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control " } })
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="btnSubmit"/>
}
```

I am not interested in a validation error message, but to have the value set to "0", by default.

Comment: public int? nummer { get; set; } change to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DefaultModelBinder` initializes your model using the parameterless constructor (your second constructor is never called). You will need to make the property nullable to prevent client and server side validation errors

```
public int? nummer { get; set; }
```

and then in the POST method, test for null and if so, set the value to `0`

```
if(!model.nummer.HasValue)
{
    model.nummer = 0;
}
```

Alternatively you could write your own `ModelBinder` that tests for a `null` value and in the `ModelBinder`, set the value to `0`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set your `nummer` field to be a nullable type, like so:

```
public class myModel 
{
    public int? nummer { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

This will allow a user to submit the form without a value entered.

Then within your controller action you will need to assign a default value if the field is null:

```
if (model.nummer == null) model.nummer = 0;
```

Alternatively, you could use a private property like so:

```
public class myModel 
{
    private int? privateNummer { get; set; }

    public int? nummer
    {
        get { return this.privateNummer == null ? 0 : this.privateNummer; }
        set
        {
            this.privateNummer = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your controller before passing the model back to the view do this ..

```
    model.find(id);
    model.nummer =0;

    return View(model)
```